# Adding threads to ExecutorService dynamically in Netty NIO

Tags: java, multithreading, netty, nio, executorservice

I want to to create an something like ExecutorService in which there will be **single thread initially**, and based on the **work load** given to the ExecutorService, the **thread count has to be increased** gradually upto certain count, say 50 for example. I could not find any way to do that.

Is there anyway make this happen in **NETTY NIO**?

Appreciate your help. Thanks.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html

Comment: Thanks JB Nizet, that is a good document. But I need a way to do the same dynamic scaling of threads in Netty NIO. I just edited the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [ThreadPoolExecutor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html). You don't really add threads yourself, rather, the pool will instantiate new threads as needed according to the load, so you start with **core** threads and new threads will be added automatically as needed up to **maxThreads**. Threads above the **core** count will stick around once they idle for the **timeout** period.

```
import java.util.concurrent.*;
....
ThreadPoolExecutor tpe = new ThreadPoolExecutor(core, maxThreads,
                                      timeout, TimeUnit.SECONDS,
                                      new SynchronousQueue<Runnable>(),
                                      threadFactory);
```

Comment: This is equivalent - apart from the timeout setting - to the simpler form [Executors.newCachedThreadPool()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newCachedThreadPool()). However, this does not answer the question which is how to set the pool size dynamically. An executor using a `SynchronousQueue` will create a thread or reuse one that is still alive for each submitted task, which can lead to an exceedingly large number of threads when the load is high.

Answer (score 0):

In netty, ChannelHandlerContext.executor() returns the Netty's EventExecutor. You can submit your Runnables to Netty's executor.

```
ctx.executor().submit(aRunnable);
```

If you want to perform an event, you might want to avoid creating your own executor service, and rely on  netty provided executor.